# String split in java script / Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have my string like this:

`selectedDates: 06/15/2015,06/14/2015,06/12/2015,06/10/2015,06/09/2015`

and I would like to have these dates in an array of strings.

When I do `var selectedDatesArray = selectedDates.split(",");`

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: selectedDates.split is not a function

What am I missing? This part of the code is in angularjs's controller.

Comment: How is selectedDates defined? I see a colon in the declaration. is selectedDates part of a json object?

Comment: selectedDates is a string that has dates seperated by a comma.

Comment: But why is there a colon in the declaration? Is it part of a json object? If yes then you will have to do thatObject.selectedDates.split(","). And also, there is no quotes around the string.

Comment: that colon is got in there because I had it in my console.log  like this  console.log('in updateScreen self.selectedDates: '+ self.selectedDates);

Comment: Try your code in Chrome's console and you should see what the problem is.

Comment: Can you share a plunker for this?

Comment: Remember that split can be applied to a string, I can see that selectedDates it's not a string. That can be the reason that you get a split is not a function.

Comment: Ok. thanks. so                                                                                            Date: <select multiple="multiple" ng-model="cntrl.selectedDates"   >
            <option ng-repeat ="date in cntrl.dates track by $index">{{date}}</option>
        </select>  does not return string (cntrl.selectedDates)?

Comment: For definition the values in a select should be strings, can you inspect and get what cntrl.selectedDates has?

Comment: this is what I have 06/15/2015,06/14/2015,06/12/2015,06/10/2015,06/09/2015

Answer (score 1):

please try this code:

```
var myStr = '06/15/2015,06/14/2015,06/12/2015,06/10/2015,06/09/2015 ';
var splitArr = myStr.split(',');
```

this should work for you.